# Backup no almacena event triggers ni extensiones

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una base de datos `PostgreSQL` (versión 9.5), la cual necesito hacerle un backup, sin almacenar los datos de las tablas.

Al hacer el backup (desde pgAdmin) selecciono `pre-data` y `post-data`.

El problema que estoy encontrando es que al hacer `restore` en una base de datos nueva vacía, las tablas y los triggers se crean correctamente, pero no hay ni rastro de los `EVENT TRIGGERS`.

También me he dado cuenta de que las extensiones tampoco son añadidas, así antes de hacer el restore tengo que añadirlas para omitir errores :

```
create extension postgis;
create extension citext;
```

¿Hay alguna opción a la hora de hacer el backup para que postgres escriba las intrucciones necesarias para añadir los event trigger y extensiones en el archivo de backup?

Answer (score 0):

Por si le es útil a algún futuro lector, actualmente no he encontrado ninguna forma de que el archivo `.backup` que genera PostgreSQL tenga incluidas las sentencias para crear `extensiones` y `event-triggers`.

Mi solución pasa por realizar un script (con NodeJS, que es con lo que estoy trabajando en mi aplicación), que haga todo el proceso de creación de la base de datos, paso a paso, en el orden en que deben crearse:

```
import { exec as exec_ } from 'child_process';
import { dbConfig } from '../../config';

const exec = require('bluebird').promisify(exec_);
let execOpts = { env : { 'PGPASSWORD' : dbConfig.password } };

async function existDatabase(){
    console.log(`Comprobando si existe la base de datos ${dbConfig.database}`);
    let commandExistDb = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '${dbConfig.database}'"`
    let promise = exec(commandExistDb, execOpts);
    return +await promise;
}

async function createDatabase(){
    console.log(`Creando la base de datos ${dbConfig.database}`)
    let commandCreate = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -c "CREATE DATABASE ""${dbConfig.database}"" "`;
    let promise = exec(commandCreate, execOpts);
    return await promise;
}

async function createExtensions() {
    console.log(`Creando las extensiones postgis y citext`);
    let command = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -d ${dbConfig.database} -f create-extensions.sql`;
    let promise = exec(command, execOpts);
    return await promise;
}

async function createTables() {
    console.log(`Creando las tablas del schema public`);
    let command = `pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "${dbConfig.user}" --dbname "${dbConfig.database}" --section pre-data --section post-data --schema public "db-only.backup"`;
    let promise = exec(command, execOpts);
    return await promise;
}

async function createCapasSchema() {
    console.log(`Creando el schema capas`)
    let commandCreate = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -d ${dbConfig.database} -c "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS capas"`;
    let promise = exec(commandCreate, execOpts);
    return await promise;
}

async function createEventTriggers() {
    console.log(`Creando EVENT-TRIGGERS`);
    let command = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -d ${dbConfig.database} -f create-event-triggers.sql`;
    let promise = exec(command, execOpts);
    return await promise;
}

async function addCapas() {
    console.log(`Creando capas`);
    let command = `pg_restore -U postgres --host localhost --port 5432 --username "${dbConfig.user}" --dbname "${dbConfig.database}" --section pre-data --section data --schema capas "capas.backup"`;
    let promise = exec(command, { execOpts }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    return await promise;
}

async function addDatos(){
    console.log(`Añadiendo datos`)
    let commandDisableTrigger = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -d "${dbConfig.database}" -c "ALTER TABLE datos DISABLE TRIGGER trg_check_gid_layer_exists"`;
    let commandEnableTrigger = `psql -U ${dbConfig.user} -d "${dbConfig.database}" -c "ALTER TABLE datos ENABLE TRIGGER trg_check_gid_layer_exists"`;
    let commandAdd = `pg_restore --host localhost --port 5432 --username "${dbConfig.user}" --dbname "${dbConfig.database}" --section data --table datos --schema public --verbose "tabla-datos.backup"`;
    await exec(commandDisableTrigger, execOpts);
    await exec(commandAdd);
    await exec(commandEnableTrigger, execOpts);
}

async function create(){
    let exist = await existDatabase();
    if(exist !== 1){
        await createDatabase();
        await createExtensions();
        await createTables();
        await createCapasSchema();
        await createEventTriggers();
        await addCapas();
        await addDatos();
    }
}

create();
```